# exec power shell script having corrective action every time

Tags: powershell, exec, puppet

Getting the corrective action for exec while using Powershell to ADD usersand groups to local admin group. Please note I am not a scripting guy, not sure what wrong I am doing.

```
Notice: /
```

Comment: You should add an `unless` or `onlyif` command to the `exec` that check the current state of the system, and prevents the main command from executing if it's as desired.  Check out the [exec resource documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/exec.html) for details.

Comment: After your last edit the question only is `Notice: /`. Very hard to give a good answer to that. Can you restore or delete your question?

Answer (score 2):

By default, an `Exec` resource is applied on every run.  That is mediated, where desired, by the resource's `unless`, `onlyif`, and / or `creates` parameters, as described in [that resource type's documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/exec.html).

The `creates` parameter is probably not appropriate for this particular case, so choose one of `unless` or `onlyif`.  Each one is expected to specify a command for Puppet to run, whose success or failure (as judged by its exit status) determines whether the `Exec` should be applied.  These two parameters differ primarily in how they interpret the exit status:

- `unless` interprets exit status 0 (success) as indicating that the `Exec`'s main command should not be run
- `onlyif` interprets exit statuses *other than* 0 (success) as indicating that the `Exec`'s main command should not be run

I cannot advise you about the specific command to use here, but the general form of the resource declaration would be:

```
exec { 'Add-LocalGroupMember Administrators built-in':
  command  => '... PowerShell command to do the work ...',
  unless   => '... PowerShell command that exits with status 0 if the work is already done ...',
  provider => 'powershell',
}
```

(That assumes that the [puppetlabs-powershell](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/powershell) module is installed, which I take to be the case for you based on details presented in the question.)

I see your comment on the question claiming that you tried this approach without success, but **this *is* the answer**.  If your attempts to implement this were unsuccessful then you'll need to look more deeply into what went wrong with those.  You haven't presented any of those details, and I'm anyway not fluent in PowerShell, but my first guess would be that the exit status of your `unless` or `onlyif` script was computed wrongly.

Additionally, you probably should set the `Exec`'s `refresh` property to a command that succeeds without doing anything.  I'm not sure what the would be on Windows, but on most other systems that Puppet supports, `/bin/true` would be idiomatic.  (That's *not* correct for Windows; I give it only as an example of the kind of thing I mean.)  This will prevent running the main command twice in the same Puppet run in the event that the `Exec` receives an event.

Comment: @Shreedhar, I have no doubt that Puppet could be made to do what you want, but you should consider whether it is the best tool for the job.  I am no kind of Windows admin, but what you describe sounds like the kind of thing that is well suited for group policy.

Comment: Well good luck to you, @Shreedhar.  You posed a Puppet question here, and I have answered it.  As I already wrote, I cannot advise you on the details of your PowerShell scripting, and I do not take that to be essential to the question (else it would be too broad for StackOverflow).  If you're having trouble getting the PowerShell bits to work then perhaps you could pose a separate question specifric to that.